# left join and sum and group by - odd behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

```
student attendance table - student_id, campus_section
campus table -  campus_section, number_of_students, campus_name
```

Sample Data:

```
Student Table: 
Student_Id, campus_section
1, ddr1
2, ddr1
3, ddr2 
4, ddr3
5, ddv1
6, ddv2
7, ddv6

Campus Table
Campus_Section, Number_Of_Students, Campus_Name
ddr1, 10, ddr
ddr2, 5, ddr
ddr3, 5, ddr
ddv1, 5, ddv
ddv2, 10, ddv
ddv3, 10, ddv
ddv6, 10, ddv
```

So the expected rows would be

```
Campus, current_students, campus_students    
ddr, 4, 20
ddv, 3, 35
```

There can be multiple campus_section rows per campus_name. The following query lists campus name along with number of students attending in that campus and total number of students in that campus.

```
select d.[campus_name] as campus_name, 
       cast(count(s.student_id) as int) as current_students, 
       sum(cast (d.[number_of_students] as int)) as campus_students 
from campus d 
left join student s 
on s.campus_section = d.campus_section  
group by d.[campus_name]
```

For some campus_name's, the result in section_students column is greater than this:

```
select d.[campus_name] as campus_name, 
           sum(cast (d.[number_of_students] as int)) as section_students 
    from campus d 
    group by d.[campus_name]
```

It means left join is doing something that it should not be for certain rows. Or maybe the second query is incorrect.

Edit: For example, the first query would give 18 for a certain campus name while the second query would give 10.

Can anybody shed some light on what is going on?  It's sql server 2008.

Comment: Can you show us expected output and actual output?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I am not supposed to post any data, but there were a couple typos in my question so please do re-read. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have to be actual data - but a very small mock sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with left join, `sum(cast (d.[number_of_students] as int))` will be number_of_students*number_of_students in a campus. Get rid of `group by` statement, you will find out why.

```
select d.[campus_name] as campus_name, 
       s.student_id, 
       d.[number_of_students]
from campus d 
left join student s 
on s.campus_section = d.campus_section
```

So the right way is:

```
select d.[campus_name] as campus_name, 
       cast(count(s.student_id) as int) as current_students, 
       cast (d.[number_of_students] as int) as section_students 
from campus d 
left join student s 
on s.campus_section = d.campus_section  
group by d.[campus_name],cast (d.[number_of_students] as int)
```

**UPDATE**
According to the data OP posted on later, need to group by campus first to get sum of section_students number, then join students table and group by campus_name to get the current_students number.

```
with campus_t as (select d.[campus_name] as campus_name, 
       sum(cast (d.[number_of_students] as int)) as campus_students 
     from campus d
     group by d.[campus_name])
select d.campus_name,
       d.campus_students,
       cast(count(s.student_id) as int) as current_students,
from campus_t d 
left join campus section
on section.campus_name = d.campus_name
left join student s 
on s.campus_section = section.campus_section  
group by d.campus_name,d.campus_students
```

Note: not tested yet. pleas check it.

Your problem came from the denormalized design. The campus table should be split to two campus and campus_section tables. That's why I have to add a CTE table named campus_t to get information of  campus entity. Your original campus table's data represents campus_section entity. If you normalize the model into three tables, that should be easier to query.

Comment: I've made a slight edit to my first query (replaced section_students with campus_Students). sum(cast (d.[number_of_students] as int)) as campus_students is supposed to represent total number of students in that CAMPUS (not section). Your approach would give me multiple rows per campus name but I want only one row per campus.

Comment: I've posted sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Sections can have more than one student. Consequently, when the tables are joined, rows in `Campus` can become duplicated, which skews your results if you try to aggregate everything in one go.

Therefore, try doing it in two steps: first do the student counts per campus section:

```
SELECT
  campus_section,
  number_of_students,
  campus_name,
  COUNT(s.student_id)
FROM
  dbo.Campus AS c
LEFT JOIN
  dbo.Student AS s
ON
  c.campus_section = s.campus_section
GROUP BY
  campus_section,
  number_of_students,
  campus_name
```

then aggregate section results per campus:

```
SELECT
  campus_name,
  current_campus  = SUM(current_section),
  campus_students = SUM(number_of_students)
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      c.campus_section,
      c.number_of_students,
      c.campus_name,
      current_section = COUNT(s.student_id)
    FROM
      dbo.Campus AS c
    LEFT JOIN
      dbo.Student AS s
    ON
      c.campus_section = s.campus_section
    GROUP BY
      campus_section,
      number_of_students,
      campus_name
  ) AS sub
GROUP BY
  campus_name
;
```